# Create C++ native code without QML

Tags: application-development

I want to create native C++ code for Ubuntu phone that is NOT QML based. In fact, I want to create native C++ code that:
 1) does not use or depend upon Qt
 2) uses SDL to bring up a window 
 3) Get a GLES2 context

In truth I am *porting* a very large code base. This code base was already ported to Android, but working with Android's NDK is pain like I have never felt before.

I've coded for N9, N900 and am quite familiar with that toolchain: scratchbox, but all I have found so far is examples of getting QML applications on the phone.

Pointers? Links?

Answer (score 1):

First, my apologies for not giving you a concrete answer. I know how frustrating it can be when you ask what is a plainly obvious question, and get no response. I just posted a similar question about an hour ago:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/284817/100-no-non-sense-native-c-c-development-or-not

I strongly suspect that you will not have the native development that you see. You are already familiar with Android's claim to support native C++ development. They even named their kit "NDK". But I don't need to tell you that every person has their own interpretation of native development.

That said, I have a gut feeling that Ubuntu is following the same path. The give you you the ability to compile C++ code into machine code, but they sandbox your application so that you do not get true native development, as in native access to the machine. Then they start giving you libraries, in a controlled mannner, piecemeal, which might turn out to be extremely frustrated.

I wish someone at Ubuntu would clear this up. And please, do not be shy. We are experienced engineers who know what compiles and translation-look-a-side buffers are. Don't beat around the bush, please. Just tell us the truth. Do we get access to the entire native API surface exposed by Linux or not?